# AS3 - Reliability of NetConnection calls using RTMFP / UDP?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, rtmfp

My applet connects to FMS4.5 using RTMFP. I open one NetConnection and stream video from the server to the applet using a NetStream. When i want to execute a function on either the applet or the server i use a NetConnection.call();

My question is does AS3 do anything internally to make sure the call over UDP happens or is there a risk of UDP loss and the function never happening when it is called?

Assuming there might be times the UDP traffic is lost i made a responder retry onStatus. Does this code look like it would actually do the job or is it overkill?

```
// This is code on FMS to call a function in the applet.

var networkRetryMax = 30;
if (something == true) doSomethingInApplet(client, 0);


function doSomethingInApplet (client, retryCount) {
    if (retryCount < networkRetryMax) {
        retryCount++;
        client.call("funcNameInApplet", new doSomethingInAppletResponder(client, retryCount), "foobar");
    }
    return;
}


function doSomethingInAppletResponder (client, retryCount) {
    this.onResult = function() {...}
    this.onStatus = function() {doSomethingInApplet(client, retryCount);}
    return;
}
```

And...

```
// This is code in the applet.
// I return true to give it something to onResult or onStatus.

public static function funcNameInApplet(result:String):Boolean {
    trace("Result: " + result);
    return true;
}
```

So would this ensure the function is called over UDP / RTMFP?

Or is .call() reliability handled internally and this is unnecessary?